# SAX Parser returns same element two times with 2nd time as empty

Tags: java, android, saxparser

My Sax parser is doing weird thing when I am trying to parse simple xml file,

This is my xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<organization>
                <employee>
                                <title>Harry0</title>
                                <link>Smith0</link>
                                <date>hs0</date>
                                <salary>200000-0</salary>
                </employee>

                <employee>
                                <title>Harry1</title>
                                <link>Smith1</link>
                                <date>hs1</date>
                                <salary>300000-1</salary>
                </employee>

                 <employee>
                                <title>Harry2</title>
                                <link>Smith2</link>
                                <date>hs2</date>
                                <salary>300000-2</salary>
                </employee>
</organization>
```

Now If I want to read only the `title` element,

```
String elementValue = null;
String localName = null;
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            this.localName = localName;
}


@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
        elementValue = new String(ch, start, length);
        if (localName.equals("title")){
            Log.e(localName,elementValue);
        }

}
```

and the output is,

```
10-19 14:41:02.261: E/title(7754): Harry0
10-19 14:41:02.261: E/title(7754):                                 
10-19 14:41:02.281: E/title(7754): Harry1
10-19 14:41:02.297: E/title(7754):                                 
10-19 14:41:02.297: E/title(7754): Harry2
10-19 14:41:02.297: E/title(7754):
```

The tag name for the empty lines as well as the title line is same, i.e. `title`

Why Sax Parser is returning everything twice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not overwrite the endElement() method. characters() may be called multiple times und you should collect the data you are interested in, not just assign it during the first call of characters().

Then the parser hits the `</title>` tag but you don't see it and collect another chunk of chars until the next `<link>` tag. You should overwrite both startElement and endElement methods, collect your strings and report them when hitting the `endElement()`